# texts = [doc.page_content for doc in documents] AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'page_content'

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42LZa.png)

I wrote this code and while running it started throwing :

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'page_content'

How to resolve this attribute error :

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'page_content'

```py
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOllama
from langchain.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
import streamlit as st 
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate


# Initialize the chat model
model_local = ChatOllama(model="mistral")

# Define function to load document
def load_document(c_file):
    if c_file is not None:
        file_contents = c_file.read()
        return file_contents
    else:
        return None

# Define function to generate response
def generate_response(query, document):
    if document:
        documents = [document]
        embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
        vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
        retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

        after_rag_template = """Answer the question based only on the following context:
        {context}
        Question: {question}
        """
        after_rag_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(after_rag_template)
        after_rag_chain = (
            {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
            | after_rag_prompt
            | model_local
            | StrOutputParser()
        )

        response = after_rag_chain.invoke(query)
        return response
    else:
        return "Please upload a C file."

# Define the Streamlit app
def main():
    st.set_page_config(page_title="Unit Test Case Generator",
                       layout="centered")
    #st.title("Unit Test Case Generator")
    
    # Sidebar for uploading C file
    st.sidebar.title("Upload C File")
    c_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Choose a C file", type=["c"])
    
    # Text box for entering query
    query = st.text_area("Enter your query:")
    
    # Submit button
    if st.button("Submit") and query:
        document = load_document(c_file)
        response = generate_response(query, document)
        
        st.subheader("Generated Output C File:")
        if response:
            st.code(response, language='c')
        else:
            st.warning("No response generated.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Python script that creates a Streamlit web application for generating unit test cases for C files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the object you try to read is byte encoded.

Have you tried `my_object.decode()` ? or even `json.loads(my_object.decode())`

use

`texts = [json.loads(doc.decode()).page_content for doc in documents]`

instead of

`texts = [doc.page_content for doc in documents]`

*json.loads()* transforms a string to an object

*str.decode()* transforms a byte-encoded string to the string itself

NB: I cannot read / search your code so this is approximative.
Could you please insert your code as text rather than image? It would be easier to use.

Comment: I tried this, texts = [json.loads(doc.decode()).page_content for doc in documents] but after that I started getting error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)".

Comment: actually your programs runs without this bug for me. Please describe a bit more the context of the error (was it on file load?? on query? somewhere else? what file was loaded? did it load properly? what query you did? (make a sample error if you do not want to share private data)